# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed FOR product_id=1100

Tags: xml

Im getting error XML Parsing Error: not well-formed for

```
<loc>http://localhost/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=8111</loc>
```

Why 1st  is not well-formed but second one is fine ? how can i fix this issue ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
<url>
<loc>http://localhost/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=8111</loc>
<lastmod>2019-05-13 13:07:07</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.7</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://localhost/new_product_test-1</loc>
<lastmod>2019-03-14 14:46:44</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.7</priority>
</url>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"? Who says it's not "valid"? In what context?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit i update the topic error show on my sitemap page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://localhost/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=8111
```

This is not well-formed because you did not escape the ampersand.

An XML parser thinks you are introducing an *entity*, but there is no such entity.

Ampersands should be encoded like `&amp;`:

```
http://localhost/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=8111
```

You can use online tools like [Yandex Webmaster's sitemap validator](https://webmaster.yandex.com/tools/sitemap/) which tell you exactly what the problem is.

The closing `</urlset>` is also missing.